# TcpClient Only Returns First Result in Spring WebFlux Controller

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have an HTTP service exposing a GET endpoint that connects to a simple echo server via TCP. The HTTP service is running on Netty.

```
@RestController
public class OurTcpClient {

    private Connection connection;

    @GetMapping("echo1")
    public Mono<String> echo(@RequestParam("value") final String value) {
        this.connection.outbound()
            .sendString(Mono.just(String.format("%04d", value.length()) + value)) // prepend length
            .then()
            .subscribe();
        return this.connection.inbound()
            .receive()
            .asString()
            .next();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.connection = TcpClient.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(10002)
            .wiretap(true)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .connectNow();
    }
}
```

My expectation is that I can query the service at, for example, http://localhost:8081/echo1?value=hi, as many times as I like, and receive "hi" back in each response. This works for the first request. The second request hangs indefinitely. If I then cancel the second request and attempt another, I get the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-13T18:56:40.221+0000",
    "path": "/echo1",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Only one connection receive subscriber allowed."
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you use `next()`

```
return this.connection.inbound()
            .receive()
            .asString()
            .next();
```

According to the `Flux#next` javadoc [Emit only the first item emitted by this Flux, into a new Mono.](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#next--), then the subscription will be canceled.

In the context of Reactor Netty when you use `next`, `timeout`, `take` etc. operators that cancel the subscription this means that the connection will be closed.

Comment: With your help, I was able to solve the issue by adding "this.hotSource = this.connection.inbound().receive().asString().cache(0);" to the init() method and amending the echo method to return "this.hotSource.as(Mono::from);". But I wonder if this misuses the .cache() method. Thanks for your help.